# CakePHP Not getting validation messages from saveMany (called from Behavior)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

So, I have a behavior that supports uploading data to the model from an Excel file.  From within this Behavior, I call saveMany, which works fine.  However, if the data are invalid, I do not get any errors, only a silent failure (I return a generic error in this case, but I want the details from the validation failure).

I'm sure there's a way to deal with this that I as a CakePHP newbie, do not know.  Here's the main function of the behavior (there's a bunch of extra logic here that probably is not germane to the problem, but I'm reluctant to cull in case it turns out to be subtly relevant) :

```
public function parseExcelFile(Model &$model, $fileInfo, $lookupKeys, $otherData = null, $referencedFields = null) {
    $allowedTypes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel');
    if ((isset($fileInfo['error']) && $fileInfo['error'] == 0) ||
        (!empty( $fileInfo['tmp_name']) && $fileInfo['tmp_name'] != 'none')) {
        // basic pre-checks are done.  Now ask PHP if it's a good file
        if (is_uploaded_file($fileInfo['tmp_name'])) {
            // it's a good uploaded file.  Now check the type
            if (in_array($fileInfo['type'], $allowedTypes)) {

                $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($fileInfo['tmp_name']);

                // Check text of header row to be sure that it hasn't been changed (equal to db field name)
                $numAltered = 0;
                $numAdded = 0;
                $schema = $model->schema();
                $newModelData = array($model->name => array()); // this is a holder for the data to be added to the model
                $fieldlist = array();   // this will be an array of field names found in the Excel file, and which we have data for
                $newData = $this->modifyDataForReferencedFields($model, $data, $referencedFields);  // $newData is now 0-based.
                for ($curCol = 0; $curCol < count($newData[0]); $curCol++) {
                    $curFieldName = $newData[0][$curCol];
                    if (!array_key_exists($curFieldName, $schema)) {
                        return 'Row header "'.$curFieldName.'" is not one of the database fields.'
                                .'  You probably altered the template in an incorrect manner.';
                    } else {
                        // set up the fieldlist and newModelData arrays
                        array_push($fieldlist, $curFieldName);
                        $newModelData[$model->name][$curFieldName] = null;
                    }
                }
                // append $otherData fields to fieldlist
                foreach ($otherData as $key => $value) {
                    array_push($fieldlist, $key);
                }

                // So, the headers seem okay, let's try to enter the data into the Model
                $saveData = array();
                for ($curRow = 1; $curRow < count($newData); $curRow++) {   // row 0 is the headers
                    // put the data into the newModelData
                    for ($curCol = 0; $curCol < count($newData[0]); $curCol++) {
                        $curFieldName = $newData[0][$curCol];
                        $curVal = $newData[$curRow][$curCol];
                        $newModelData[$model->name][$curFieldName] = $curVal;
                    }
                    $existingID = $this->existingID($model, $lookupKeys, $newModelData[$model->name]);
                    if ($existingID) {
                        // we must be updating a model entry, so set the ID
                        $newModelData[$model->name]['id'] = $existingID;
                        $numAltered++;
                    } else {
                        // otherwise, unset
                        unset($newModelData[$model->name]['id']);
                        $numAdded++;
                    }

                    // Add in the fixed fields
                    foreach ($otherData as $key => $value) {
                        $newModelData[$model->name][$key] = $value;
                    }
                    array_push($saveData, $newModelData);
                }
                $options = array('fieldlist' => $fieldlist);
                if ($model->saveMany($saveData, $options)) {
                    return 'From the uploaded file, '.$numAdded.' records were added and '.$numAltered.' records were updated.';
                } else {
                    return 'There was a problem with the uploaded data.';
                }
            } else {
                return "The chosen file was not one of the allowed types.";
            }
        } else {
            return "There was something wrong with the upload process.";
        }
    } else {
        return "No file was chosen for uploading.";
    }
}
```

And here is the controller action that is called upon upload form submission:

```
public function processUpload() {
    // now parse the file in the model
    $result = $this->Instructor->parseExcelFile(
        $this->data['Instructor']['bulkData'],
        array(  // field(s) for looking up data in the model to see if we are adding or updating
            'username',
        ),
        array(  // a set of fixed fields to add to all entries, new or updates
            'department_id' => $this->request->data['Instructor']['department_id'],
            'role' => 'instructor',
            'password' => '')
    );
    $this->Session->setFlash($result);                  
    $this->redirect($this->referer(), null, true);
}
```

Thanks in advance.
-Dave

Answer (score 1):

The Model has some methods that could be invoked in order to check records. You should be able to use 
[Model->validateMany()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelvalidateMany)
The Model class also has some other manual validation methods:

[Model->validateAssociated()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelvalidateAssociated) which is used to validate a single record, as well as all its directly associated records and [Model->validates()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelvalidates) which returns true if all fields pass validation.

Check the DataValidation section of the [Cake Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html). Cake 2.2.x also introduces the concept of [Dynamically Changing validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules), which could come in very handy.

Cheers! :)

Comment: But aren't the data getting validated already during the save?  Actually, I know that they are because invalid data fail to save.  It's not the validation, it's the flash messages that I am missing.  Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Well the validation should be called during the save, but it could be that you're calling the `saveMany()` from withing the Behaviour which does not in any way communicate with the view.